# How to know if your app is being blocked by a company?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, office365api

We are building a web app that lets Office365 customers create a realistic plan for their week, by showing them how much time they actually have to work each day (it's called [Weekly](https://www.planweekly.io) if you're interested).

The problem we are running into however is that some companies, primarily large ones, block apps entirely from making Microsoft Graph calls to their users. What's tricky is that we send them to Office365 to grant us permissions, their company blocks the access request, and we never see those users again, so currently don't have any way of knowing what happened.

We'd like to be able to display our own message that says something like "Your company has blocked access to our application, please contact your IT department for help".

Is there any way of knowing before sending the user over to grant access that their company (the domain) even allows apps? If not is there some way to send the user back to the requesting app with some details about why the grant failed (did the user not grant permissions, did the company block access, etc.)?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

If the administrator disables the ability for users in the organization to consent then the error message will be something like:

> AADSTS90093: An administrator of {tenantDisplayName} has set a policy that prevents you from granting {name of app} the permissions
>   it is requesting. Contact an administrator of {tenantDisplayName}, who
>   can grant permissions to this app on your behalf.

https://apps.dev.microsoft.com/portal/tools/errors?errorName=graph_user_unauthorized

Comment: Yina - thanks for replying. We've encountered this error before with users, so are familiar with it, the question was more, is there a way as an app builder to deal with it more gracefully? For example could we somehow query for that user to see if their company blocks applications outright, or could we somehow have the user navigated back to us if they hit this error. As an app builder the experience is really bad. The user goes to our site, they go to Office 365 to login and consent, they see an error. That's it.

Comment: Sam - I hear you, we are working on making the experience better. I don't have timelines to share, but one of the places that we are investing on is allowing users to reach out to the admins and start approval workflows. Would love to hear additional ideas from you on how we can improve the experience, can I kindly ask that you start a userVoice request for this? https://officespdev.uservoice.com/ and tag it with Microsoft Graph.